# How to split a csv line at every 5th character in Bash?

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I am new to linux and trying to figure out things. Although there are some similar examples on net, I dont have enough knowledge to modify them to my needs (Sed is.. hard to interpret), apologises for this.

My question is; I have a single line text (csv) file (column number varies 50-150), like below:

```
20,30,10,50,4,6,14,5,24,1.19,2,23,4000,12,56,43,1.2,78,334,77...etc.
```

What I want to do first is make a paragraph break after every 5th number then **delete last number of every new line** so it will look like;

```
20,30,10,50

6,14,5,24

2,23,4000,12

...etc
```

How can I handle this in Bash?

Thanks for the answers.

(May worth to mention about one next step. I will try to convert above into this;

```
somefixedtext,20,30,10,50,someotherfixedtext

somefixedtext,6,14,5,24,someotherfixedtext

somefixedtext,2,23,4000,12,someotherfixedtext

...etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks indeed to @Cyrus, his solution worked perfectly for me.

```
sed -ri 's/([ \,]+[^ \,]*){1}$//' ${f}
sed -ri 's/([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*),[^,]*,/\1\n/g' ${f}
sed -i 's/.*/somefixedtext,&,someotherfixedtext/' ${f}
```

Comment: Only the last line relates to this question. And the pipe is wrong: because you're using `-i`, there's no output to pipe into the 2nd sed. Just put those 2 commands on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with this command:

first split it into lines and sed merge 5 lines to one

```
cat yourFile | tr ',' '\n' | sed -e 'N;N;N;N;s/\n/,/g'
```

Comment: Don't forget that he wants to remove the last number from each line.